# Preload/Prime Amazon Cloud Front CDN before move.

Tags: amazon-web-services, cdn, amazon-cloudfront, high-volume

I am changing CDNs and I would like to preload some content to AWS Cloud Front so that my origin server is not hammered during that transition. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your CloudFront distribution and...

- make CloudFront the CDN in a randomly selected 1% of pageviews
- write a script to request all commonly used image paths from the CloudFront distribution at whatever pace you prefer

Comment: Do you know of any CDNs that allow you to "preload" content by uploading it somewhere?

Comment: Anything that isn't "origin-pull" essentially works that way. It removes the big benefit of origin-pull, though, which is that if you forget to put a file on the CDN it isn't a problem, the CDN just pulls it off your server. You could do this with CloudFront by switching to an S3 bucket backed distribution instead of a custom origin.

Comment: The first option described is really the only way to go, as the second option would only prime the cache in one Amazon edge location.

Comment: @rmalayter Great point.